# How to use Boost on release mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

i'm new in boost library , i built my application in release mode and i got those 2 errors:

- impossible to open the source file "boost\filesystem.hpp" No such file in directory
- impossible to open the source file "boost/lexical_cast.hpp" No such file in directory

Thanks in advance,
Cheers , 
@niz-dam

Comment: Seems you forgot to add your include paths for release mode. I expect you probably also missed the library paths. Remember that each configuration (Debug, Release, RelWithDebugInfo, ...) has independent settings.

Comment: How to add include paths for release mode, for debug configuration i just add the path in : C/C++  -> General -> other directories include
& Linker ->General -> Directories of additional libraries

Comment: Its the exact same thing for release mode. Just make sure you have the correct configuration selected when you add the settings.

Comment: Thanks i resolved the problem.